# Auto compose for ^ and ¨ (Ubuntu KDE 20.10)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, compose-key

in the french language you are very often using the `ê` character, but to write it I need each time to hit compose + the `^` and `¨` key (maj+`^` gives `¨`) + `e`, which makes 3 keys for 1 character. Is it possible that when I hit `^` or maj `¨` it automatically enables the "compose" mode so I can just type ê without typing ^e each time ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is more or less how a layout with dead keys works. For example, with the US international keyboard, it takes two key presses, the dead key (^ or ") followed by the character. With a dedicated French keyboard, it would take a single keypress. I don't think that can be configured this way with the Linux "Compose" key system. Would be good to add to your question what keyboard layout you use.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your hint @vanadium !
I indeed set a "no dead keys" keyboard in the input options for whatever reason, and choosing the same without "no dead keys" fixed my issue.